# How to implement Pushbots on ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, push-notification

want to make push notification in ionic but after some research i got some some clues but its not sufficient .  i am bit confused  how to initialize the pushbot because on net only pushgap example are available , if any alternative available kindly tell thanks in advance . following are  code  my code

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic','app.controllers', 'app.routes', 'app.services', 'app.directives'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);


    }

    window.plugins.PushbotsPlugin.initialize("57f383574a9efa904d8b4567", {"android":{"sender_id":"438608897686"}});


    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: It is the same thing. Simply use `cordova` examples. What is not working ?

Comment: kindly provide the link

Comment: Your code seems good. How do you have imported the plugin ? Did you use `cordova plugin add` ?